Limiting number of logs in a blob file in Azure functions log to Blob Storage
I am using Serilog to put responses I get in form of logs through swagger, to a file in Azure Blob storage container.
Below is the startup.cs code (it was in program.cs but tried to add in startup for trying):-

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)     
  {
      var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
      var allowedOrigin = _configuration["AllowedHosts"];
      services.AddDBContext(connectionString);        //added code for application insights        
      services.AddControllersWithViews ();
      services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
      services.AddSingleton(_configuration); 
      Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(_configuration)        
      WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage(new BlobServiceClient(newUri("https://dsicentralusdevsa02.blob.core.windows.net"),
       new DefaultAzureCredential()),
       storageContainerName: _configuration.GetValue<string>("Serilog:storageContainerName"), 
        writeInBatches: true,  
       period: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
         batchPostingLimit: 1,
         storageFileName: $"/{{yyyy}}/{{mm}}/{{dd}}/{{HH}}/{{Guid}}.txt")     
   .CreateLogger(); }   `

I want get only one response in a single text file generated in blob container , however I get 2 response when 2 logs are generated at an interval of 2-5 seconds.
I want only one response or log having one dealID to be stored in a single file and other ID in another file.
I have tried to limit the time interval in which a new file is generated from swagger for response but the time interval is minimum set for 1 min and I want it to be a minimum of 2 seconds.
Is there a way to add condition to filter response in file based on DealID or anyother way to limit only one response in single file
on using this , i have got only a single file in blob , when a new response is generated within a few seconds interval (like 1-3 seconds).
Although the two logs/responses have different DealID they are added to same file, i have tried to have a unique file name but it doesnt work.

Is this Function app or Web app?

If it is Function app can you provide more details like, Is it isolated or In-process, .net version?

hi @AsleshaKantamsetti , It is a web -app and is isolated which is running on .net version 3.1 .

Is it web app 3.1 core?

Yes , it is web app 3.1 core.
